# excel to put sequence number but skipping two rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need one help regarding excel. I want to add the sequence number in sheet 1 from sheet 2 by 
    skipping 2 rows in between. For e.g. as defined below. Row1 will lookup 1 from sheet 2, row 2 & row 3 
    should be blank and then row 4 will pick 2 from sheet2

```
Sheet1                  Sheet2
Row1 >>1                   1
Row2 >>blank               2
Row3 >>blank               3
Row4 >>2
```

Answer (score 0):

=IF(ROW()/3=INT(ROW()/3),INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,ROW()/3),"")

This assumes you start at row 1. And that the sheet 2 stuff is all in column A.